# vb.net linked vs embedded resources weird result - VS 2017 CE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

**This suppose to be a simple issue; not to be posted as a question in stack overflow!**

Following this article: [How to: Create Embedded Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7(v=vs.100).aspx)

1. I had created a new and fresh `Form1.vb` to test in Visual Studio 2017 community edition.
2. Added a big `testfile.WAV` file as a test resource.
3. Checked the link type is set to default value:  "Linked at compile
   time" [Default Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KlgS.jpg).
4. Clean/Build/Rebuild the application.

---

- Still no matter what I do, the `result.exe` file is so big and reflect the big `testfile.wav` file size, and can't at any situation find the wav file as a linked resources in separate file in `bin\Debug` folder!
- Tried to alter almost everything everywhere; yet no success!
- What I expect is to have both `result.exe` and `testfile.wav` in `bin\Debug` folder separately linked and not embedded.

---

Looks very weird to me? is it a bug in VS or in app setting?

Thank you so much
Appreciated any hint

**Note**: What I was trying to reach is to create a different themes for my application, where users can chose the appearance; and my efforts break in the above scenario. It doesn't make sense that `result.exe` ends in 10s of MB if it will include resources inside it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If you want it as a loose file then you need to have it as a loose file. Resources are always embedded in the application.

If you add the resource via `Project Properties > Resources` then it will always be embedded in your application.

If you want it as a loose file then you shall just import it to your project via `Add Existing Item` and set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the item to `Copy Always`. Then you reference it by doing for example:

```
Dim WavPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "yourfile.wav")
Dim WavFile As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(WavPath)
```

Linked vs Embedded only make a difference at design time. Linked resources are still embedded in your application, but at design time you may edit them and can easily add or remove other resources.

Embedded resources however are embedded in a `.resx` file even at design time, and to edit such resources you have to export them or change them into a linked resource. Embedded resources are mostly used when you need to share the same resources in multiple projects. The resources are then embedded in the `.resx` file so you only need to copy that and not every included file.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the reason there is two options? `Linked at compile time` And `Embedded in .resx.`. And why output is always the same? Is there a specific reason why changing this option doesn't change anything? its more convenient to access resources through `My.Resources.MyFile` than Dim it in code.

Comment: @wpcoder : The two options only make a difference at design time. When the application is compiled there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TL;DR! Saved my day.

Comment: @wpcoder : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: I guess its good if we can have it to reflect in runtime as well. Designer is the interface to compile ....accepted answer but not very convenient from VS2017.

Comment: @wpcoder : You've not been able to use resources as loose files in any VS version. I think the problem is that `My.Resources` is an auto-generated class which operates in a certain way... Still though, that doesn't stop you from making your own class which behaves the same but loads the file from disk.